# grep number of occurrences a string exists in a bunch of files

Tags: groovy, count

I want to count the number of times a certain string occurs in all text files inside a folder and all its sub folders.

The command for doing this using grep on Linux would look something like this

```
grep string * | wc -l
```

Any ideas how to do this using groovy instead?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, your `grep|wc -l` command won't do what you want you need the `-o` option. otherwise it sum the lines which containing the pattern. not the `the number of times a certain string occurs`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`assert 2 == ['a','b','c','a'].grep ( ~/a+/ ).size()`

where `['a','b','c','a']` will be simply `readLines()` from the file You need to process or file collection.

It also works on file object:

```
def f = File.createTempFile('111','222')
f.deleteOnExit()
f.text = "a\na\nb\nc"
assert 2 == f.grep(~/a+/).size()
```

An the sample solution:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def parent = File.createTempDir()
parent.deleteOnExit()
def f1 = File.createTempFile('111','111', parent)
f1.deleteOnExit()
def f2 = File.createTempFile('222','222', parent)
f2.deleteOnExit()
def f3 = File.createTempFile('222','222', parent)
f3.deleteOnExit()
f1.text = 'aa\naa\nbb'
f2.text = 'cc\nbb\nbb'
f3.text = 'cc\ncc\naa\naa'

def files = []
parent.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  files << file
}

assert 4 == files.collect { f -> f.grep(~/a+/).size() }.sum()
```